# Teapot Riddle no. 14

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, homonym

This is my first teapot riddle so hopefully all goes well.
I am sure most people know the deal but for any who doesn't, there is one word with two or more meanings (two teapots). Try and figure out the word from these hints:

> The first teapot is kinda like a square,
>
> While the second teapot is daring beyond compare.
>
> Teapot number one can contain all sorts of things,
>
> But teapot number two is contained in a ring.
>
> Finally, teapot one can help you move so you get it all done.
>
> Whereas teapot two is a way of moving that can be lots of fun.
>
> **What am I?**

Comment: EDIT : Are all the grammatical errors intended?

Comment: No sorry I've just always been bad with that...

Comment: Ok then, will fix those errors :D

Comment: And BTW, try not putting dates on the title of ur riddles (I don't think that will attract attention) :D

Comment: @gabbo1092 Cool riddle even thought i couldn't figure it out. Is this no.14 ? Could you rename this riddle for finding issues

Comment: @Jannis Sure I can rename it. What do you mean by no. 14 ? Sorry I’m fairly new here still haven’t quite figured out the naming convention for these.

Comment: @gabbo1092 it's no real convention but finding your riddle and integrating it in the series is easier if you write the number, since they get linked in related. And since teapot no15 hasn't linked this riddle its even harder. I needed to especially search for this riddle to find it ... and its quite a nice riddle :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is,

> Teapot 1: (Boxing)A Box, or a Container

based on:

> **The first teapot is kinda like a square,** - Box
> **Teapot number one can contain all sorts of things,** - Box
> **Finally, teapot one can help you move so you get it all done.** -> you will require boxes to move to a different place, to carry all your stuff

And from [El-Guet](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/50778/el-guest),

> Teapot 2: Boxing - sport

Explanation :

> While the second teapot is **daring** beyond compare.
> But teapot number two is contained in a **ring**
> Whereas teapot two is a way of moving that can be lots of fun. - moving -> part of Boxing

Comment: +1 It has to be a box :)

Comment: But what about the second teapot? :-)

Comment: You are right with first teapot. Can you find the second?

Comment: Maybe something to do with r13(tybirf naq chapuvat), perhaps.

Comment: @El-Guest can I try that in my answer?

Comment: Absolutely! I’d recommend it @NaeemShaikh

Comment: thanx @El-Guest

Comment: My pleasure @NaeemShaikh! Great answer!