# Teapot Riddle no.17

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Teapot riddle no.17:
should i write fanmade or not? not quite sure...
Rules:
I have **one word** which has **several** (2 or more) **meanings.**
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
You try to figure out the word with my Hints.

First Hint:

> My first teapot is not a place where you should lay down
>   My second teapot is a place where you could lay down, but without any reason that's quite strange
>   My third teapot is part of a place where you normally lay down

Second Hint:

> My first teapot can move up an down
>   My second can move normal
>   If someone sees my third teapot moving please send me a pic

Third Hint:

> My first teapot is assumed soft but is actually pretty bony
>   My second teapot sounds soft, like a Harley on steroids
>   On my third teapot soft can't be applied

Final Hint(makes it really easy):

> My first teapot lets you fly
>  My second teapot too
>  My third teapot can't fly

Good luck and have fun :)
Thanks to everyone contributed to this series <3
last 5 riddles:
[16](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72517/teapot-riddle-no-16-fan-made)
[15](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72462/teapot-riddle-no-15-fanmade)
[14](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72456/teapot-riddle-no-14)
[13](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72448/teapot-riddle-no-13-fan-made)
[12](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72439/teapot-riddle-no-12)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I feel I'm way off, but is it a

> Wing  (Bird wing, wing, a unit of military planes, Wing of a building)

My first teapot is not a place where you should lay down
My second teapot is a place where you could lay down, but without any reason that's quite strange
My third teapot is part of a place where you normally lay down

> you should not lay down on a bird wing!  If you are flying as part of a military wing, you probably won't be laying down.  Your bedroom, however, might be part of a wing of the building

My first teapot can move up an down
My second can move normal
If someone sees my third teapot moving please send me a pic

> Bird wings flap, military wings move normally, and building wings generally don't move

My first teapot is assumed soft but is actually pretty bony
My second teapot sounds just soft
On my third teapot soft can't be applied

> Bird wings are bony, Military wings...er.. don't sound soft, soft isn't a word associated with part of a building

And the final hidden hint

> Bird wings allow birds to fly, military wings also fly, and buildings can't fly.

Comment: Ohh, for the first hint maybe about laying your head on it is because pillows can have feathers in them :D +1