# Teapot Riddle no.18

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Teapot Riddle no.18
Rules:
I have **one word** which has **several** (2 or more) **meanings**.
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
You try to figure out the word with my Hints.

First hint

> My first teapot is hurting
>   My second teapot is hurting way too much

Second Hint

> My first teapot is an escape
>   My second teapot is the exit

Third Hint

> My first teapot is a pleasure
>   My second teapot can be too

Final Hint

> My first teapot is less deadly than my second teapot,
>  but is responsible for more deaths

Good luck and have fun :)
[More fun](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72549/teapot-riddle-no-17)

Comment: extra HInt: add to each line of the second Hint 'from reality'

Comment: extra Hint: alkoholics

Comment: I was thinking of rot13(fubgf). But doesn't qualify the third hint. :)

Comment: @VivekParekh thats right ;) quick make an answer out of this comment, you solved it

Comment: @VivekParekh why are you thanking me? You figured it out on yourself! Congrats ;)

Comment: You cleared my doubt :)

Comment: Alkoholics as in people that have a problem drinking, not the hip hop group from Los Angeles.... it all makes sense now

Comment: @Jim a band like that exists? sry ... :/ hope you had fun nevertheless

Comment: @Jannis I always do : ) .    (Not sure if links are appreciated here but this is what I was searching for the answer in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tha_Alkaholiks)

Comment: @Jim ... I think funny, not far: i wouldn't let you search in a wiki article.   I think, there the puzzling loses a bit fun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it

> Shots?

First hint

My first teapot is hurting

> Alcohol Shots

My second teapot is hurting way too much

> A shot from a gun?

Second Hint

My first teapot is an escape

> Alcohol shot helps to escape the reality

My second teapot is the exit

> Gun shots helps to exit the reality

Third Hint

My first teapot is a pleasure

> Alcohol shots can be taken for one's pleasure

My second teapot can be too

> Gun shots maybe for those who likes to hunt

Final Hint

My first teapot is less deadly than my second teapot,
but is responsible for more deaths

> Alcohol maybe causes more death than gun shots.

Comment: Are the teapots correct? I mean, the second teapot, gun shots?

Answer (score 1):

Here we go. I'm not sure about this one, but my guess is

> INTOXICATION

Meanings:

> Alcohol intoxication. Poisoning.

My first teapot is hurting. My second teapot is hurting way too much

> Alcohol intoxication has some undesirable effects. Poisoning hurts.

My first teapot is an escape. My second teapot is the exit

> Getting drunk allows people to "escape from their problems". Getting poisoned can kill you.

My first teapot is a pleasure. My second teapot can be too

> People like getting drunk. Death can be something desirable for certain people.

My first teapot is less deadly than my second teapot, but is responsible for more deaths

> Alcohol is less deadly than poison, but alcohol causes way more deaths than poison.

Comment: Poison isnt the second teapot, but good guess. :) keep on you can do it

Comment: Just to be clear: I used "poisoning" in a broad meaning (food poisoning, carbon monoxide poisoning, poison poisoning). Is it wrong as a whole, or is the answer a more specific kind of poisoning?

Comment: @Rasco The only poision i meant is the alkohol