# Teapot Riddle no.19

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Teapot Riddle no.19
Rules:
I have **one word** which has **several** (2 or more) **meanings**.
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
You try to figure out the word with my Hints.

First Hint

> It's dark when you see my first teapot
>   It get's dark when you see my second teapot

Second Hint

> My first teapot has it's own superhero
>   My second teapot has more heros

Third Hint

> My first teapot technique looks highly advanced
>   My second teapot technique looks pretty primitive

Final Hint

> My first teapot has eyes, but known as blind
>  My second teapot has no eyes

Goodluck and have fun :)
[More riddles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72622/teapot-riddle-no-18)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Bat

It's dark when you see my first teapot

> This is referring to the animal  - a bat

It get's dark when you see my second teapot

> This could when somebody hits you with a baseball bat.

My first teapot has it's own superhero

> Batman

My second teapot has more heros

> Baseball

My first teapot technique looks highly advanced

> Bats look like complex creatures

My second teapot technique looks pretty primitive

> A baseball bat looks like a pretty simple device

My first teapot has eyes, but known as blind

> Blind as a bat

My second teapot has no eyes

> Baseball bats do not have eyes

Comment: Thats right ... that went fast

Comment: Dang it! I thought I finally answered a teapot puzzle first :P

Comment: first place goes to hexomino, @nikki and gabbo1092,  when did figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

Your word is

> Bat

It's dark when you see my first teapot

> Bats fly at night

It get's dark when you see my second teapot

> If you're hit with a bat?

My first teapot has it's own superhero

> Batman

My second teapot has more heroes

> Cricket players

My first teapot technique looks highly advanced

> RADAR

My second teapot technique looks pretty primitive

> Just hit with the bat

Comment: I'm on phone, idk why I can't edit it right

Comment: try some line breaks ... idk either

Answer (score 1):

Is the answer

> Bat?

It's dark when you see my first teapot

It get's dark when you see my second teapot

> first teapot is bat the animal which are often nocturnal therefore out at night. Second teapot is a baseball bat and if you were to see one coming towards you everything would go dark as you pass out.

My first teapot has it's own superhero

My second teapot has more heroes

> first teapot is referencing Batman and second is referencing baseball heroes.

My first teapot technique looks highly advanced

My second teapot technique looks pretty primitive

> Bat's technique for the first is referencing echolocation, second teapot bat's are similar to a primitive club of sorts.

My first teapot has eyes, but known as blind

My second teapot has no eyes

> Bat's have limited visual sight and use echolocation, baseball bat's don't have eyes.