# Teapot Riddle no.20

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Teapot Riddle no.20
Seems teapots are getting META in this game :D
Rules:
I have **one word** which has **several** (2 or more) **meanings**.
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
You try to figure out the word with my Hints.
*Did someone not know the rules until now?*

First Hint

> My first teapot is really shocking
>   My second teapot is really annoying

Second Hint

> My first teapot can be a pleasure
>   My second teapot on warm days too

Third Hint

> My first teapot can be dangerous without safety
>   My second teapot can be dangerous when overgetting massively

Final Hint

> My third teapot is used in the music, to make songs really cool;
>  without it music would be just the lame same

Good luck and have fun :)
[easy last riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72639/teapot-riddle-no-19)

Comment: The answer is not Rot13(orng), is it? I am just guessing, hahah :P

Comment: You're right, the answer is not rot26(Beat)

Comment: @user477343 Do you now need hints? :D

Comment: Nah, I'm fine. I was just not active for a while (haven't been on YouTube in *ages*), but I'm back now :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be far-fetched, but perhaps the answer is

> DROP?

Meanings:

> To DROP from a height. DROPS in the rain. A DROP during a musical track.

My first teapot is really shocking. My second teapot is really annoying

> Falling is shocking. Rain is annoying.

My first teapot can be a pleasure. My second teapot on warm days too

> Parachute jumping is cool for some people. Rain can be nice in hot days.

My first teapot can be dangerous without safety. My second teapot can be dangerous when overgetting massively

> If you fall, you can get hurt. Too much rain is dangerous.

Final Hint

> My third teapot is used in the music, to make songs really cool; without it music would be just the lame same

-

> Drops in electronic music are considered cool.

Comment: nice work :) , now quick figure out [no.18](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72622/teapot-riddle-no-18) ... it's still leftover

Comment: Funny, I thought this after I saw the final hint but couldn't get it to match up. Nice one :)