# Teapot Riddle no.21

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Teapot riddle no.21
Rules:
I have **one word** which has **several** (2 or more) **meanings**.
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
You try to figure out the word with my Hints.
*no further words needed, right?*

First Hint

> My first teapot is on the ground
>   My second teapot is in the air

Second Hint

> My first teapot is plain
>   My second teapot is advanced

Third Hint

> My first teapot is unsorted
>   My second teapot is very structured

Final Hint

> My first teapot can have a promontory
>  My second teapot has a nose

Good luck and have fun :)
[last riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72646/teapot-riddle-no-20)

Comment: Oh, this is too easy. I am not going to look at the answer, but am very certain I know what it is (I like maths, so that helps) :P

Comment: @user477343 easy is not bad, actually the question was answered by the third person looking at this, so i feel free to say its hard enough to be entertaining. And sometimes easy riddles are nice to solve

Comment: rot13: V unir ab vqrn jung n cebzbgbel vf, V guvax lbh zrna cebzbagbel.

Comment: [look here ... thats a promontory](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/promontory)... | next that google transaltor said me it's also a word for nose

Comment: I agree, but sometimes *too* easy riddles are frowned on by users on this site :\

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the teapot is

> Plane

My first teapot is on the ground

> A plane is a flat surface or flat area of land.

My second teapot is in the air

> Plane is also short for aeroplane

My first teapot is plain

> Flat planes are not very interesting to look at

My second teapot is advanced

> (Aero)planes are a technological achievement.

My first teapot is unsorted

> Mathemetical planes have affine symmetry so we can move them around and they look the same

My second teapot is very structured

> (Aero)planes have a lot of structure to them.

My first teapot can have a promotory

> A promotory is a raised mass of land that projects into a lowland (plane)

My second teapot has a nose

> An (aero)plane has a nose.

Comment: Jop thats right... that went faster than the 19th ridldle

Comment: I think it was the last hint that clinched it for me. I was trying to think why you would mention a nose and not any other part of a face.