# Teapot Riddle no.24

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Teapot Riddle no.24:

This is about a word in which I'm not quite sure where my translator is fooling me.
Forgive me if I have a translation that's wrong.

Teapot riddle rules:
I have **one word** which has **several** (2 or more) **meanings.**
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
You try to figure out the word with my Hints.

First Hint:

> My first teapot is pushing things
>   so strong that they fall

Second Hint:

> My second teapot is an attention-grabbing action,
>   so quiet, no one's hearing it

Third Hint:

> My third teapot is a concentration-grabbing action,
>   so genius you will figure out

Forth Hint:

> My fourth teapot is so polluted
>   that you won't want to clean up

Fifth & Final Hint:

> My fifth teapot is the top,
>  the 'top'

Good luck and have fun :)

Thanks to all makers of the teapot riddles.

[Teapot riddle 23](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72791/teapot-riddle-no-23-fan-made)
[Teapot riddle 22](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72761/teapot-riddle-no-22-fan-made)
[Teapot riddle 21](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72677/teapot-riddle-no-21)

Comment: Five teapots? Wow. DVL15 $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Comment: I was also planning on making another fan made teapot riddle, but that would make it the 25th teapot riddle, and that sounds a bit more special than the other ones. Would you like to do that one instead?

Comment: @user477343 i dont mind ... maybe I do sth 'special' at 50th or 100th riddle, but I'm not sure how to make a 'sepcial' riddle. should it be extra hard or should it contain more riddles in itself or sth else. I'm open and very gracious about cool ideas

Comment: I don't know, to be honest. I was planning to do just another teapot riddle about another teapot word :P

Comment: @user477343 go for it, [just do it] (https://tenor.com/view/justdoit-gif-4618831), I no director of this series ..., I'm just a guy addicted to writing these things

Comment: Actually, nah, I won't make it. There is another name for it that might cause confusion. In fact, it has heaps of different names when doing research... but I'll make a riddle about one of the things it includes :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it

> Tip

...pushing things so strong, that they fall

> Tip something over

...an attention-grabbing action, so quiet, no ones hearing it

> Tip your hat

...concentration-grabbing action,so genius you will figure out

> I may need a hint for this one... ;)

...so polluted, that you wont want to clean up

> You shouldn't clean a tip (dump) since that's where you put rubbish.

...Fifth hint

> TOP = POT backwards... 
>  Tip + Pot = Ti Pot ≈ Teapot...  Maybe?
>  Oh - or top = "tip of the iceberg" if your brain's less fuzzled than mine.

Comment: Nice one, :), you definetly sound like a fresh dude.   When did you figure it out? And actually i thougth of to tip/touch/tap someone as second hint

Comment: for this word i could have a [dozen more teapots...](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tip)

Comment: For the first clue it was the first word that sprang to mind; and confirmed by the fourth... for the others I had to think a little before realising that it fitted those definitions too.  Nice one / thank-you :).

Answer (score 5):

Is the word:

> WAVE ?

First teapot: pushing things so strong, that they fall

> Forces travel in waves, so can push things over. It is theorised that the force of gravity travels in waves and this makes things fall.

Second teapot: attention-grabbing action, so quiet, no ones hearing it

> You can get somebody's attention by silently waving at them.

Third teapot: a concentration-grabbing action

> Feelings also come in waves, such as "a wave of concentration".

Fourth teapot: so polluted, that you wont want to clean up

> The sea is polluted, and has waves. But *do* lets clean it up!

Fifth teapot: the 'top'

> Your hair can be a 'wave', and that sits on top of your head.

Comment: I'm sorry its not the word, but cool try ;)

Comment: Or ROT13(unve pna or jnil (nxn abg dhvgr pheyl, ohg qrsvavgryl abg fgenvtug))

Answer (score 3):

Certainly a stretch, but I haven't answered in a while :-) Is it:

> Saw

First Hint:

> It's more 'cutting' but let's argue that the teeth are "pushing" the material out of it's way.  Saw a tree, it comes down

Second Hint:

> Saw, the past tense of "see."  Something I see, catches my attention

Third Hint:

> An [old saw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saw_(saying)) - a proverb of sorts.  Concentrate to figure out the true meaning

Fourth Hint:

> [Saw Mill River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saw_Mill_River) Ok, so there appear to be clean up efforts, so it doesn't really fit.  But it **is** polluted

Final Hint:

> A (see)saw.  At one point, you are at the top!  At least until you come back down...

Comment: Nice try .. it's not the word though, sry. But the word has actually just 3 chars, so you just have to consider 26³ -1 other possibilities XD, when do you make your own teapot riddle?

Comment: Haha, I guess I'll just start brute-forcing the answer ;-) Hmm... maybe I'll think of one.  I enjoy trying to answer, not sure how good I'll be at coming up with clues though

Comment: I just know the teapot word and then I'm writing sh!t about the abilities that both teapots have in common. Job's done :)

Comment: Lol, good to know! I'll start thinking :-)